# Seekbar too little

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I'm following an example in my book, but I can't get the seekbar in the said example to be large enough as the book shows and even the example code from the book site shows.
this is the layout declaration and the concerned row. Do you know what is the difference related to?

Expected Result and given result (yes the book was made for 2.3):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QT9j.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Cpr.png

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tableLayout" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:background="#FFF" 
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:stretchColumns="1,2,3" >

<TableRow
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tableRow0">

   <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/billTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/billTotal"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:paddingRight="5dp" />

  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/billEditText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_span="3"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
     android:layout_weight="1">

  </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
   android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tenTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_column="1"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="10%" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/fifteenTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="15%"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/twentyTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="20%"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/tip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tip10EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tip15EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tip20EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/total" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/total10EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/total15EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/total20EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

</TableRow>

 <TableRow
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tableRow4">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/customTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/custom" 
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:paddingRight="5dp"
     android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
     android:focusable="false"/>

  <SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_span="2"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:paddingLeft="8dp"
      android:paddingRight="8dp"
      android:progress="18" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/customTipTextView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="18%"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"            
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:layout_weight="1"
         />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipCustomTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/tip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tipCustomEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalCustomTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/total" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/totalCustomEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text="@string/zero" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: im not able to reproduce this given the code below which makes me wonder if the code your leaving out could be causing it ?

Comment: there's no other code. There are just obvious indentation problems because I'm new to stack overflow and it seems a bit strange to me that I have to add four spaces to every single line I want to be highlighted as code. I can pastebin it to give you better indentation. and I can also give you the code of the example of the book, which, substituted to this code, gives the right layout. thanks